# Integration tests with Arquillian WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type XXXX with qualifiers @Default

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly, cdi, jboss-arquillian

I'm creating my first EJB test with Arquillian and I'm facing something that seems very common taking in mind the number of posts with the same problem. But after trying all suggestions I've been unable to find a solution.

I'm running it over a wildfly14.

My test class:

```
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import javax.inject.*;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class LicenseManagerTest {

@Deployment
public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
    WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
                    .addClasses(LicenseManager.class)
                    .addPackages(true, "package1", "package2");
    return war;
    }

@Inject
private LicenseManager licenseManager;

@Test
public void getAboutTest() {
    Assert.assertNotNull(licenseManager.getAbout().getText());
    }
}
```

EJB Manager:

```
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface LicenseManager {

AboutDTO getAbout();

}
```

BEAN class:

```
@Stateless(name = "LicenseManagerEJB3")
@Remote(LicenseManager.class)
public class LicenseManagerBean implements LicenseManager{

@Override
public AboutDTO getAbout(){
    *My code goes here*
}

}
```

**Arquillian.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
<defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0"/>
<container qualifier="widlfly-managed" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="jbossHome">target/wildFly-14.0.1.Final</property>
        <!--<property name="managementAddress">127.0.0.1</property>-->
        <!-- Port offset allows running the tests while a WildFly server is already running -->
        <property name="javaVmArguments">-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=10000 -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m --add-modules java.se</property>
        <property name="managementPort">19990</property>
        <property name="username">admin</property>
        <property name="password">admin</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

**POM file**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>artifactName</artifactId>
<parent>
    <groupId>package1</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactName</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../name1/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<properties>
    <version.arquillian>1.4.1.Final</version.arquillian>
    <version.wildfly>14.0.1.Final</version.wildfly>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>false</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Project dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${version.arquillian}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>${version.arquillian}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-core-api</artifactId>
        <version>${version.arquillian}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.1.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jconsole</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>wildFlyManaged</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <testResources>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                </testResource>
            </testResources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>unpack</id>
                            <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>unpack</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                                        <version>${version.wildfly}</version>
                                        <type>zip</type>
                                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                        <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

During the test configuration, several EJB's that have mixed dependencies with mine, are started without problem, but LicenseManagerEJB3 is not, and when the test code is executed I get the following error:

> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type LicenseManager with qualifiers @Default
> at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private package1.LicenseManagerTest.licenseManager
> at package1.LicenseManagerTest.licenseManager(LicenseManagerTest.java:0)
> at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:83)
> at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:70)
> at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.createInjectionTarget(BeanManagerImpl.java:1025)
> at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.createInjectionTarget(ForwardingBeanManager.java:204)
> at deployment.0d8da7a8-dc23-4657-ac07-40964685a2c1.war//org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.cdi.CDIInjectionEnricher.injectNonContextualInstance(CDIInjectionEnricher.java:143)
> at deployment.0d8da7a8-dc23-4657-ac07-40964685a2c1.war//org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.cdi.CDIInjectionEnricher.injectClass(CDIInjectionEnricher.java:125)
> ... 142 more
> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type LicenseManager with qualifiers @Default
> at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private package1.LicenseManagerTest.licenseManager
> at package1.LicenseManagerTest.licenseManager(LicenseManagerTest.java:0)
> at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:378)
> at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:290)
> at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateProducer(Validator.java:425)
> at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.InjectionTargetService.validateProducer(InjectionTargetService.java:36)
> at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.validate(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:153)
> at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:81)
> ... 147 more

Do you know what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `beans.xml` in the Deployment, therefore CDI does not find any beans in the archive, because CDI is not enabled for the archive.

Try to add the `beans.xml` into your deployment via:

```
archive.addAsResource("META-INF/beans.xml);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Thomas, but if I didn't undersand it wrong since javaee7 there's no need of beans.xml file, I even tried adding an empty beans.xml during the createDeployment method.
From the tests I've been performing it seems more something related to maven dependencies. If I add a direct dependency to the project where the injected class is found, the CDI icon appears inmediatly on my IntelliJ, but the problem is that my project is old and huge (100+ diferent modules) and if I do this I get maven cycles...

Comment: I think you are right, since CDI 1.2 or 2 you need no beans.xml anymore but I think discovery mode is then annotated but your EJB has no CDI annotation. Or EJB is not working properly. Did you try to inject it with @EJB? And also its only a remote EJB maybe it needs  @Local. For classloading issues try to get the class via Class.forName() to check if its available. If it doesn't work could you provide a sample project on github?